# How to return json in columnar form for Pandas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, pandas

By default, the JSON response is **rowise** , each row means a whole record in database.

How to convert the below JSON in  columnar form ?

```
{
CFTC_Commodity_Code: "967",
CFTC_Contract_Market_Code: "967654",
CFTC_Region_Code: "01",
},
{
CFTC_Commodity_Code: "167",
CFTC_Contract_Market_Code: "9654",
CFTC_Region_Code: "02",
},
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to read this json into pandas, or to output it from pandas?

Comment: Hi @joris my partner told me he prefer to read  JSON in **columnar**,   so I'm trying to output the format to Pandas.

Comment: I still don't understand: do you have data in a pandas DataFrame and do you want to use `DataFrame.to_json`, or do you want to import a json file with `pandas.read_json`?

Comment: I don't know the Pandas, and I don't need to handle it.I only have data in MongoDB and provide an webapi to return JSON data . someone will invoke the API to get returned json. he will input the returned data  into Pandas. But Pandas perfers columnar JSON. can you understand ?

Comment: You should specify your question with that. Pandas can handle a lot of different formats, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#reading-json. Probably the `'records'` format will be ok.